# Fast way to see common observation counts for Python Pandas correlation matrix entries

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, missing-data

Suppose I have a `pandas.DataFrame` called `df`. The columns of `df` represent different individuals and the index axis represents time, so the (i,j) entry is individual j's observation for time period i, and we can assume all data are `float` type possibly with `NaN` values.

In my case, I have about 14,000 columns and a few hundred rows.

`pandas.corr` will give me back the 14,000-by-14,000 correlation matrix and it's time performance is fine for my application.

But I would also like to know, for each pair of individuals (j_1, j_2), how many non-null observations went into the correlation calculation, so I can isolate correlation cells that suffer from poor data coverage.

The best I've been able to come up with is the following:

```
not_null_locations = pandas.notnull(df).values.astype(int)
common_obs = pandas.DataFrame(not_null_locations.T.dot(not_null_locations),
                              columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
```

The memory footprint and speed of this begin to be a bit problematic.

Is there any faster way to get at the common observations with `pandas`?

Comment: you can partially solve this by passing ``min_periods`` to corr (e.g. its a cutoff where you require that minimum number of observations; doesn't directly answer but may give you a 'good enough' answer

Comment: That's a great suggestion, but I'm working in a production system that requires Pandas version 0.8.0, and it looks like `min_periods` was added in a newer version. Nothing I can do about the out of date version, I'm afraid.

Comment: you could *add* it in the code (and recompile) if on linux (where pretty easy).....its only a couple line change (of course 'production' maybe preclude this....)

Comment: Yeah, they'd never allow that. It would be faster to go through the long process of approving an upgrade to Pandas. But your point was really helpful since I did not know about that option. At least in the dev system where I can switch between Pythons, I can use this idea there.

Comment: To be even more tricky, you can use ``pyximport`` and in YOUR code to a dynamic cython change to the code base in your project! (basically monkey-patching)); you basically create a new function and overwrite the old one (or better yet, just copy the cython function in nancorr and call it directly yourself?)

Comment: Try grouping by user, loop over user groups, calculate `common_obs` for each group, then accumulate using `.add(ct, fill_value=0)` (which is a good trick if ever wanting to populate the accumulation matrix with newly-seen categories). Hey presto, should keep your memory footprint down!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, but would need to cythonize (otherwise much slower); however
memory footprint should be better (this gives the number of nan observations, your gives number of valid observations, but easily convertible)

```
l = len(df.columns)
results = np.zeros((l,l))
mask = pd.isnull(df)
for i, ac in enumerate(df):
    for j, bc in enumerate(df):
           results[j,i] = (mask[i] & mask[j]).sum()
results = DataFrame(results,index=df.columns,columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually make @Jeff's answer a little faster by only iterating up to (but not including) `i + 1` in the nested loop, and because correlation is symmetric you can assign values at the same time. You can also move the `mask[i]` access outside of the nested loop, which is a tiny optimization but might yield some performance gains for very large frames.

```
l = len(df.columns)
results = np.zeros((l,l))
mask = pd.isnull(df)
for i in range(l):
    maski = mask[i]
    for j in range(i + 1):
           results[i,j] = results[j,i] = (maski & mask[j]).sum()
results = DataFrame(results,index=df.columns,columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score -1):

Both answers above are wrong, once you have to pass what is NOT NULL to have a True, and make the comparisons column-wise instead of row-wise. I managed to have the right answer through:

```
l = len(df.columns)
results = np.zeros((l,l))
mask = pd.notnull(df).values
for i in range(l):
    maski = mask[:,i]
    for j in range(i + 1):
        results[i,j] = results[j,i] = (maski & mask[:,j]).sum()
results = pd.DataFrame(results,index=df.columns,columns=df.columns)
```